# duda con función PIVOT de SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Estoy realizando una consulta que me muestre una agrupación de datos y hasta ahora todo bien, pero quisiera además agregar una columna que muestre el total de registro por organismo.

Adjunto el script de mi consulta y los resultados:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT
    r.tb_idRegion AS cantidad,
    r.abreviatura AS region,
    o.abreviatura AS organismo
    FROM tb_construccion c
    INNER JOIN tb_organismo o ON o.tb_idOrganismo = c.tb_idOrganismo
    INNER JOIN tb_propiedad p ON p.tb_idPropiedad = c.tb_idPropiedad
    INNER JOIN tb_region r ON r.tb_idRegion = p.tb_idRegion
    WHERE c.tb_idEstadoConstruccion = 1
) t
PIVOT(
    COUNT(cantidad)
    FOR region IN (
        [XV],
        [I],
        [II],
        [III],
        [IV],
        [V],
        [RM],
        [VI],
        [VII],
        [XVI],
        [VIII],
        [IX],
        [XIV],
        [X],
        [XI],
        [XII])
) AS tb_pivot
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Volviendo a mi problema, me gustaría agregar una columna TOTAL que calculara las cantidades por organismo.

Cualquier ayuda es bien agradecida :)

Saludos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes guardar el resultado de tu tabla pivoteada en un common table expresion y luego realizar funciones de agrupamiento sobre las nuevas columnas del CTE

```
;WITH Pivoted 
AS
(
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT
    r.tb_idRegion AS cantidad,
    r.abreviatura AS region,
    o.abreviatura AS organismo
    FROM tb_construccion c
    INNER JOIN tb_organismo o ON o.tb_idOrganismo = c.tb_idOrganismo
    INNER JOIN tb_propiedad p ON p.tb_idPropiedad = c.tb_idPropiedad
    INNER JOIN tb_region r ON r.tb_idRegion = p.tb_idRegion
    WHERE c.tb_idEstadoConstruccion = 1
) t
PIVOT(
    COUNT(cantidad)
    FOR region IN (
        [XV],
        [I],
        [II],
        [III],
        [IV],
        [V],
        [RM],
        [VI],
        [VII],
        [XVI],
        [VIII],
        [IX],
        [XIV],
        [X],
        [XI],
        [XII])
) AS tb_pivot
)
SELECT cantidad,region,organismo,Sum([I]+[II]....)
FROM Pivoted
GROUP BY cantidad,region,organismo
```

Comment: No necesitas el WITH, con cambiar el asterisco por la lista de columnas. Tampoco es con SUM, porque ya está agregado.

Comment: @ExCrEed Gracias por tu respuesta, lo implemente y funcionó perfecto! solo tuve que añadir en el ultimo select todas mis regiones.

Answer (score 2):

Para agregar una columna total, sólo tienes que agregar la suma del resto de las columnas.

```
SELECT organismo,
       [XV],
        [I],
        [II],
        [III],
        [IV],
        [V],
        [RM],
        [VI],
        [VII],
        [XVI],
        [VIII],
        [IX],
        [XIV],
        [X],
        [XI],
        [XII],
        total = [XV]  + [I]   + [II]   + [III] + [IV]  + [V] + [RM] + [VI] 
              + [VII] + [XVI] + [VIII] + [IX]  + [XIV] + [X] + [XI] + [XII]
FROM
(
    SELECT
    r.tb_idRegion AS cantidad,
    r.abreviatura AS region,
    o.abreviatura AS organismo
    FROM tb_construccion c
    INNER JOIN tb_organismo o ON o.tb_idOrganismo = c.tb_idOrganismo
    INNER JOIN tb_propiedad p ON p.tb_idPropiedad = c.tb_idPropiedad
    INNER JOIN tb_region r ON r.tb_idRegion = p.tb_idRegion
    WHERE c.tb_idEstadoConstruccion = 1
) t
PIVOT(
    COUNT(cantidad)
    FOR region IN (
        [XV],
        [I],
        [II],
        [III],
        [IV],
        [V],
        [RM],
        [VI],
        [VII],
        [XVI],
        [VIII],
        [IX],
        [XIV],
        [X],
        [XI],
        [XII])
) AS tb_pivot;
```

Sin embargo, siempre me ha parecido más claro (y versátil) la opción que tenemos desde antes de que se introdujera el operador PIVOT, que son los agregados condicionales.

```
SELECT
    o.abreviatura AS organismo,
    COUNT( CASE WHEN r.abreviatura = 'XV  ' THEN r.tb_idRegion END) AS [XV],
    COUNT( CASE WHEN r.abreviatura = 'I   ' THEN r.tb_idRegion END) AS [I],
    COUNT( CASE WHEN r.abreviatura = 'II  ' THEN r.tb_idRegion END) AS [II],
    COUNT( CASE WHEN r.abreviatura = 'III ' THEN r.tb_idRegion END) AS [III],
    COUNT( CASE WHEN r.abreviatura = 'IV  ' THEN r.tb_idRegion END) AS [IV],
    COUNT( CASE WHEN r.abreviatura = 'V   ' THEN r.tb_idRegion END) AS [V],
    COUNT( CASE WHEN r.abreviatura = 'RM  ' THEN r.tb_idRegion END) AS [RM],
    COUNT( CASE WHEN r.abreviatura = 'VI  ' THEN r.tb_idRegion END) AS [VI],
    COUNT( CASE WHEN r.abreviatura = 'VII ' THEN r.tb_idRegion END) AS [VII],
    COUNT( CASE WHEN r.abreviatura = 'XVI ' THEN r.tb_idRegion END) AS [XVI],
    COUNT( CASE WHEN r.abreviatura = 'VIII' THEN r.tb_idRegion END) AS [VIII],
    COUNT( CASE WHEN r.abreviatura = 'IX  ' THEN r.tb_idRegion END) AS [IX],
    COUNT( CASE WHEN r.abreviatura = 'XIV ' THEN r.tb_idRegion END) AS [XIV],
    COUNT( CASE WHEN r.abreviatura = 'X   ' THEN r.tb_idRegion END) AS [X],
    COUNT( CASE WHEN r.abreviatura = 'XI  ' THEN r.tb_idRegion END) AS [XI],
    COUNT( CASE WHEN r.abreviatura = 'XII ' THEN r.tb_idRegion END) AS [XII],
    COUNT(*) AS total
FROM tb_construccion c
INNER JOIN tb_organismo o ON o.tb_idOrganismo = c.tb_idOrganismo
INNER JOIN tb_propiedad p ON p.tb_idPropiedad = c.tb_idPropiedad
INNER JOIN tb_region r ON r.tb_idRegion = p.tb_idRegion
WHERE c.tb_idEstadoConstruccion = 1
GROUP BY o.abreviatura;
```

Comment: Gracias @Luis Cazarez, probaré esta forma de implementar que me parece interesante